# Increasing count of number every second?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want a function to happen 5 sec after onload. Then, that function should change the value of a div every second. Basically, the div has a number, whose value i want increased every second , until 100. Here's what I have come up with so far:

```css
div {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<body onload="setTimeout(start,3000) ; setTimeout(end,3000) ">
    <div id = number>
    1
    </div>
    %
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    
    setInterval(
    var a = (function start() {
    i = i%100 + 1;
    return i;
    }); , 1000) 
    
    setInterval(
    var earth =  document.getElementById('you');
    
    function end (){
    earth.innerHTML = a; 
    
    }
    
     )  
    
    
    </script>
</body>
```

No luck so far. Pls tell me where i went wrong and correct it pls. A fiddle would be  appreciated :D .

Comment: Hi Pranav, Can you please put this in a fiddle and share us a workable link to check the functionality?

Comment: your main problem is that you put `var` in your call to `setInterval`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do what you're asking for:

```js
setTimeout(start, 5000);

var i = 1;
var num = document.getElementById('number');

function start() {
  setInterval(increase, 1000);
}

function increase() {
    if (i < 100) {
      i++;
      num.innerText = i;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="number">1</div>
```

Comment: Answers to questions tagged with merely `javascript` should not include the use of frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go use `setTimeout` for 5sec gap , after that use `setInterval`

```js
var counter = 0;
var div = document.getElementById('spinner');
setTimeout(function(){
    var st = setInterval(function(){
    div.innerHTML = ++counter;
    if (counter > 100){
        clearInterval(st);
    }
  },1000)
},5000);
```

```html
<div id ="spinner"></div>
```

Comment: This has an infinite while loop on line 6 of the Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You should not put `onload` in your `<body>` tag.

Instead, use it in your JavaScript with [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Answer (score 0):

Make it as a function

```
function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(
      function() {
         //stuff
      }, 5000);
}
```

Then execute it onload

```
onload="myFunction();"
```